# Eigenvectors and Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Would an eigenvector, with every entry being the same number, be a possible eigenvector for a matrix, if and only if, that matrix is symmetric?

Example:

[ n; n] is a possible eigenvector of A, if an only if A = [ a b; b a ]

** ";" implying the next row of the matrix**

Sorry if this is confusing, I don't feel I did a great job describing my question. I'll try to help if you are confused. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A class of counterexamples are the (right) stochastic matrices, i.e. the matrices with positive entries, whose rows sum up to 1, that are not symmetric. For any stochastic matrix $A$, 
$$A \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ \vdots \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ \vdots \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$$
Explicit example in dimension 2: $$A= \begin{pmatrix} 1/2 & 1/2 \\ 1/3 & 2/3 \end{pmatrix}$$
Edit: In general $$A \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ \vdots \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}= \lambda \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ \vdots \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$$
if and only if all rows of $A$ sum to $\lambda$.

Edit 2: You seem to be thinking of symmetry as symmetry along the diagonal AND the anti-diagonal (the usual definition is only along the diagonal, so a symmetric matrix in dimension 2 is $A= \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ b & c \end{pmatrix}$).

In dimension 2, that notion of symmetry happens to imply coinciding row-sums. In higher dimensions that direction is no longer true either. Example: 
$$A = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 0):

Already hife has answered it; the vector $(n,n)$ is an eigen vector iff $(1,1)$ is. And when we multiply a matrix by a (column) vector of all 1's the components of the resulting vector are simply the sums of entries in the corresponding row. For this to be a scalar multiple of $(1,1)$ we need all the row sums to be equal (the eigenvalue will then be that row sum). So the matrix need not be symmetric. Note that this applies to matrices of arbitrary size not just $2\times2.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @Hife shows that the "if" part is false. The "only if" part is also false -- if you take almost any symmetric matrix, and compute its eigenvectors, you will find that none of these eigenvectors has all of its elements equal to each other.